# Change Step Size in JS Countup Animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I have been playing around with variations on this wonderful CodePen example of a JavaScript count-up animation: https://codepen.io/jshakes/pen/KKpjdYv.

I'm interested in changing the step size of the counting action - i.e. counting by 2's, 3's, 5's, etc. instead of by single digits. So far, I have tried changing the value of the `frame` variable as well as adding values to `totalFrames` and `progress`, but am unable to achieve different step sizes. Does anyone have any idea how to go about implementing this? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/jshakes/pen/KKpjdYv

HTML

```
<button onclick="runAnimations()">Animate</button>
<ul>
  <li><span class="countup">45</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">110</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">53210</span></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
// How long you want the animation to take, in ms
const animationDuration = 10000;
// Calculate how long each ‘frame’ should last if we want to update the animation 60 times per second
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;
// Use that to calculate how many frames we need to complete the animation
const totalFrames = (Math.round( animationDuration / frameDuration ) + 5);
// An ease-out function that slows the count as it progresses
const easeOutQuad = t => t * ( 2 - t );

// The animation function, which takes an Element
const animateCountUp = el => {
    let frame = 0;
    const countTo = parseInt( el.innerHTML, 10 );
    // Start the animation running 60 times per second
    const counter = setInterval( () => {
        frame++;
        // Calculate our progress as a value between 0 and 1
        // Pass that value to our easing function to get our
        // progress on a curve
        const progress = easeOutQuad( frame / totalFrames );
        // Use the progress value to calculate the current count
        const currentCount = Math.round( countTo * progress );

        // If the current count has changed, update the element
        if ( parseInt( el.innerHTML, 10 ) !== currentCount ) {
            el.innerHTML = currentCount;
        }

        // If we’ve reached our last frame, stop the animation
        if ( frame === totalFrames ) {
            clearInterval( counter );
        }
    }, frameDuration );
};

// Run the animation on all elements with a class of ‘countup’
const runAnimations = () => {
    const countupEls = document.querySelectorAll( '.countup' );
    countupEls.forEach( animateCountUp );
};
```

Comment: Change `easeOutQuad` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `step` parameter to `animateCountUp` and only increment `currentCount` in multiples of the step. In this example I've made each counter increment according to its index (so the first increments by 1, the second by 2, the third by 3):

```js
// How long you want the animation to take, in ms
const animationDuration = 5000;
// Calculate how long each ‘frame’ should last if we want to update the animation 60 times per second
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;
// Use that to calculate how many frames we need to complete the animation
const totalFrames = (Math.round( animationDuration / frameDuration ) + 5);
// An ease-out function that slows the count as it progresses
const easeOutQuad = t => t * ( 2 - t );

// The animation function, which takes an Element
const animateCountUp = (el, step) => {
    let frame = 0;
    const countTo = parseInt( el.innerHTML, 10 );
    // Start the animation running 60 times per second
    const counter = setInterval( () => {
        frame ++;
        // Calculate our progress as a value between 0 and 1
        // Pass that value to our easing function to get our
        // progress on a curve
        const progress = easeOutQuad( frame / totalFrames );
        // Use the progress value to calculate the current count
        const currentCount = Math.floor( ( countTo * progress + step - 1) / step) * step;

        // If the current count has changed, update the element
        if ( parseInt( el.innerHTML, 10 ) !== currentCount ) {
            el.innerHTML = currentCount;
        }

        // If we’ve reached our last frame, stop the animation
        if ( frame === totalFrames ) {
            clearInterval( counter );
        }
    }, frameDuration );
};

// Run the animation on all elements with a class of ‘countup’
const runAnimations = () => {
    const countupEls = document.querySelectorAll( '.countup' );
    countupEls.forEach((el, i) => animateCountUp(el, i+1) );
};
```

```html
<button onclick="runAnimations()">Animate</button>
<ul>
  <li><span class="countup">45</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">110</span></li>
  <li><span class="countup">348</span></li>
</ul>
```